# Uniform limit of orientation-preserving homeomorphisms again orientation-preserving?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, uniform-convergence, orientation

Basically, the question title is what I'm curious about. Suppose you have a sequence of orientation-preserving homeomorphisms $(f_n)_n$ from an orientable connected manifold $X$ to another manifold $Y$ of the same finite dimension; if necessary and/or convenient, one may additionally assume that $X$ is compact and with (non-empty) boundary. Furthermore, assume that $X$ and $Y$ carry metric structure, i.e. there are metrics $d_X$ and $d_Y$ on $X$ and $Y$, respectively, so that we're able to talk about uniform convergence (without any further need of mathematical tools). Now suppose that the sequence $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly on $X$ to a homeomorphism $f: X \longrightarrow Y$. **Is it true that the limit mapping $f$ is orientation-preserving as well?**

In other words: I'd like to know if (under the appropriate circumstances) the property "*orientation-preserving*" has the same persistence property under uniform convergence as continuity, for it is well-known that the uniform limit of continuous mappings is again continuous.

I really searched for quite a bit of time now in order to find a (partial) answer to this question, but unfortunately was not able to find any reference. Actually, the question is motivated from a more concrete situation stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3699698/can-quasiconformal-mappings-converge-uniformly-to-a-homeomorphism-that-is-not-qu). Any help, reference or hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know about the definition of orientation of a topological $m$-manifold $M$ in terms of local homology groups $H_m(M, M-x)$, $x\in M$?

Comment: I've heard very few things about it a long time ago, but have never been familiar with it, unfortunately...is there a good reference you can recommend for this (and related) topic?

Comment: Any textbook on algebraic topology (which discusses homology groups) will have it. The standard reference these days is Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology." There is an alternative argument which works with fundamental class (for closed manifolds) or relative fundamental class (for compact manifolds with boundary). But all the proofs I know use homology groups.

Comment: Ok I took a look at Hatcher's (very well written!) book, in particular pp. 234 ff. where he defines orientation of n-manifolds in terms of local homology groups/local orientations...my problem in understanding is how does one bring in orientation-preserving homeomorphisms here, and how is this helpful for my problem? (As I said, I'm not at all familiar with homology theory or related concepts from algebraic topology, unfortunately)

Comment: I do not have time for a detailed answer but the key is that (assuming that $X$ is compact)  if $||f_n-f||$ is small and $f_n(x)=f(x)=y$ for some point $x$, then the maps $f_n, f$ will be homotopic as maps of pairs $(X,x)\to (Y,y)$, hence, will induce equal maps of relative homology groups. If $X$ is noncompact (the case you care about), in this argument one considers maps of pairs $(B,x)\to (C,y)$, where $B, C$ are small compact balls in $X, Y$, and uses excision.